# Mutex lock and a number of threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I have an API (written in `C`) that permits any number of incoming (concurrent) connections. Each connection is handled by an independet `pthread` created whenever a client connects to the API.
Each of these connections can (but do not have to) change properties of the server such that requests should not be processed at the same time.

My code basically follows this structure:

```
pthread_mutex_t lock;
void request_handler(char * request)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    process_request(request);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

Assume now one request is being processed that takes a long time (e.g. ten seconds). In this time, five other requests come in, so five *additional* `pthreads` will reach at the `pthread_mutex_lock` function.

- Do they just wait there and continue as intended (one after another is served)?

The reason why I'm asking this is that this is what I'd expect but I haven't found an example with more than one concurrent thread in the official documentation.

- Is there a guarantee that the requests will be processed in the same order in which have been received or will *any* single one of the five waiting threads be allowed to start after the long request finished?

Strict in-order execution is *not* needed by my code, but I'd like to know beforehand what to expect in order to design my code properly.

I also read about recursive `mutex`, but I'd like to avoid them due to a number of reasons. Furthermore, my code will not try to lock multiple times from one single `pthread` by construction.

Comment: No, there is no order guaranteed. The first one to acquire the lock after it was released will get it. There is no queueing mechanism. You'd need a semaphore if you wanted to control the order.

Comment: What @Coldspeed says but, in reality, it's very likely that the OS will queue the waiting threads to the mutex and release them in the order they 'arrived', just don't bank on it :)

Comment: first off, creating/destroying a thread is time consuming.  much better to have a 'thread pool' (google for the details) then all the creation time is at the beginning of the program and all the destroying is at the end of the program and it only happens once rather than on each connection/dis-connection

Comment: the posted code will serialize the handling of the connections.  much better to not serialize and simply hand the request off to an available thread to process it.

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for your suggestion, but my application is designed for usage on low-performance hardware rather than HPC and I'd rather not have a high number of threads idling around and consuming resources (I don't know beforehand how many threads I'd need at maximum). Hence, I'm willing to invest the costs for creating threads as it improves the readability of the source code. The requests are serialized as some requests might result in a resize of the data structure and this could easily lead to serious trouble if that happens multiple times at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mutex ensures that exactly one thread enters the critical section of your code, in your case, the call to `process_request()`, at a time. Once a thread `t` obtains the lock, any subsequent thread must wait until `t` releases it.

If multiple such threads arrive, who gets a chance to go first depends on the scheduling of the threads by the operating system, which is not deterministic and can be different each time you run the program. However, the guarantee is that it will be only one thread that can pass, each time.